# HashMap accessing same ArrayList

Tags: android, string, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying the following to update the `HashMap` with new value of student, please check where I'm  missing something.

```
ArrayList<Student> tempStudentList = XMLParser.studentHashMap.get(currentSectionName);

if(studentList==null)
{

    Log.v(CURRENT_SCREEN,"created another student list for section name:"+currentSectionName);
    tempStudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

} 
Log.v(CURRENT_SCREEN,"Added student to the list");

tempStudentList.add(currentStudent);

XMLParser.studentHashMap.put(currentSectionName, tempStudentList);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough context - we don't know what's going wrong, for example, or where `student` is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wanted to write `tempStudentList` instead of `studentList` at the null check.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking the wrong variable for null. Also, Java collections are mutable, the array in studentHashMap is manipulated directly so you don't need to perform another put after every query on your map:

```
ArrayList<Student> tempStudentList = XMLParser.studentHashMap.get(currentSectionName);

if(tempStudentList == null)
{
    Log.v(CURRENT_SCREEN, "created another student list for section name:"+currentSectionName);
    tempStudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    XMLParser.studentHashMap.put(tempStudentList);
} 

tempStudentList.add(currentStudent);
Log.v(CURRENT_SCREEN,"Added student to the list");
```